# How to set a number of indexes in an array to compare them and return the smallest value

Tags: c#, arrays, input, integer

Okay, so basically, I have something to do for class and can't get my head around it, most of my code is done and I just need a way to put a minimum and maximum so my code compares the numbers in the array and returns the smallest value.

The code asks what index the user chooses 2 numbers(0 to 3) and then, if the users chooses 1 and 2, the code has to compare the numbers 1 and 2 and return the smallest value.

```
class Program
{
    static int FindSmallestValue(int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
    {
        int minimum = array[indexMin];
        for (int i = 0; i <= indexMax; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < minimum)
            {
                minimum = array[i];
            }
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The smallest value is {0}", minimum);
        return minimum;
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 64, 28, 42, 37 };
        Console.WriteLine("Input the first index(0 à 3)");
        int indexMin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Input the second index(0 à 3)");
        int indexMax = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        FindSmallestValue(array, indexMin, indexMax);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to start your `for` loop iterator variable `i` at `indexMin` not `0`. so... `for(int i = indexMin; i <= indexMax; i++)`...

Answer (score 1):

As @FrankM_DN said, Your code starting `for` loop from `0th` index. Instead of starting from 0, start `for` loop from `minIndex`.

```
for(int i = indexMin; i <= indexMax; i++)
{
   ... //Your code goes here
}
```

---

If you are using C# 8.0 or higher version you can do it using [`range operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) i.e `..`

```
var minFromSlicedArray = array[indexMin..^indexMax].Min();
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IvErqr)